# Assigning names from a vector if it is found in a variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to create a variable which pastes names from a vector if it is found in an existing variable. Example below.

```
words = c('jump','man')
test = data.frame('strings'=c('jumping','ok','manual'))
```

Desired output:

```
test = data.frame(
'strings'=c('jumping','ok','manual'),
'want'=c('jump',NA,'man')
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
test %>% 
    mutate(want = str_extract(strings, str_c(words, collapse="|")))
```